# Observation of negative voltage at the output of the op-amp

Tags: operational-amplifier, analog, integrated-circuit

I am using ADA4898 op-amp.
Without connecting any elements to the circuit at the output of the IC, I see a negative voltage.
Is my IC broken?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2flX7yP.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fbSNG6.png)</sup>

Answer (score 4):

You're running the op-amps open loop so the slightest difference between the inputs will drive the output to saturation.<sup>1</sup>

Connect the output to the inverting input to make a unity gain buffer and the output should go to 0 V.<sup>2</sup>

---

<sup>1</sup> Op-amps have very high gain of 100,000 to 1 million or more. That means that any input offsets due to imperfections of the op-amp get amplified by that factor and show up on the output. For that reason we use negative feedback to control the gain and correct any non-linearities in the amplifier.

<sup>2</sup> With negative feedback the amplifier output will settle down when the inverting input is at the same voltage as the non-inverting input.